# What kind of operation is allowed to be executed during onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

I decide to execute some code before popping up the confirm exit dialog box.

However, the behavior of `onbeforeunload` is quite puzzling. Certain operations are allowed, and certain operations aren't allowed.

```
function dummy() {
    alert('123');            // Not allowed. Blocked alert('123') during beforeunload
    console.log('123');      // Allowed.
    navigator.vibrate(1000); // Doesn't work in my chrome mobile.
    return "do you exit";
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return dummy();
}
```

I was wondering, why there's such behavior? Is there any documentation on this behavior?

Is there any workaround to overcome the restriction post on navigator.vibrate before returning popup string?

Comment: The "why" is pretty straight forward. Why would anybody want websites to aggressively prevent you from leaving them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find that the Mozilla Development Network [does have documentation on this sort of thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

To quote:

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

And as for the why, meager has nicely pointed out in the comments that websites should not be allowed to aggressively prevent you from leaving the page.

`navigator.vibrate` is a time-based function. "Vibrate for x milliseconds". When the window is unloading, it does not want the user to have to wait for *anything*. You might be able to find a workaround for this, but I suspect that it will be patched as this is not desirable functionality.